# Sturmey Archer 3-speed hub adjustment

Tags: hub, internally-geared-hub, speed, adjustment, sturmey-archer

I am going crazy here. I have a SA SRF3 mounted on a 16 inch wheel Dahon bike I bought second hand. The bike needed some love and I managed to put it to my liking. Unfortunately I reached a dead end with the SA hub. I am on my 50th attempt of setting up the the damn thing, I looked at countless online manuals and tip and tricks. There’s no way to know I have the right tension on the chain as I pull on it to the max and never see the start of the indicator rod, is it possible it’s too short? Or is there another way to adjust it? I am willing to buy an indicator rod but how to know the right length?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me

Answer (score 1):

It is correctly adjusted when the cable is quite taut (Plays a note when plucked) in the lowest gear and really quite slack in the highest gear. Your 1:1 middle ratio should then be in correct adjustment.

Replacement indicator rods are cheap but provided you can get your lowest gear, you shouldn’t need one.

---

Sturmey Archer S-RF3

Details

- 3 Speed internal gear hub without brake (freewheel)
- 175mm axle length
- Classic 3 speed gear ratio of 177%

Specs:

- Hub Shell Material: 6061 Aluminium
- Axle Diameter: 13/32" Slotted
- Axle Length: 175.0mm
- Over Locknut Dimension: 127mm
- Right Axle Protrusion Length: 24mm
- Left Axle Protrusion Length: 24mm
- Spoke Holes: 36H
- Pitch Circle Diameter: 67mm
- Center to Flange Right: 28.6mm
- Center to Flange Left: 28.0mm
- Flange Width: 53mm
- Spoke Compatibility: 13g or 14g
- Sprocket Teeth: 13T through 22T
- Chain Line: 1/8" Flat 43.1mm
- Chain Line: 1/8" Dished 41.5mm, 44.9mm
- Chain Line: 3/32" Flat 42.7mm, 43.5mm
- Chain Line: 3/32" Dished 41mm, 45mm
- **Indicator Chain: HSA420 Mark 5**
- Weight: 1060g

Gear Ratios:

- Overall Range: 177%
- Gear 1: 75% (-)25%
- Gear 2: 100% Direct Drive (Gear 1 + 33%)
- Gear 3: 133% (+)33% (Gear 2 + 33%)

Includes SL-S30 3 Speed Thumbshifter and 1/8 Inch 18T Dished Sprocket.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your indicator chain is too short.

According to the [parts list for the S-RF3 hub](https://www.sturmey-archer.com/files/catalog/files/309/PART%20LIST%20-%20AW%20SRF3.pdf) here is the correct part number for the indicator chain based on axle length.

[image]
[image]

With the correct indicator chain installed [the adjustment instructions provided in the manual](https://www.sturmey-archer.com/files/catalog/files/309/MANUAL%20-%203%20SPEED%20HUBS.pdf) should work.

[image]